# JNA: How to pass a string as void* from Java to C

Tags: java, jna

I have successfully *received* a void* from a C function into Java and cast it into the apropriate type depending on context, but now I have to do the whole thing the other way around, and I can't get it to work.

Specifically, the function I am trying to call demands a void*, behind which, in this case, hides a char*, behind which of course hides a char[]. The C-function doesn't manipulate the data, it just reads it.

So I've tried creating a Byte[] from a string and then passing a pointer to the first element of it, like so:

```
    //transform the string into a byte array
    byte[] byte_value = new_value.getBytes();
    //create a pointer to the first byte
    ByteByReference valueptr = new ByteByReference(byte_value[0]);
    //pass the pointer to the function that sets the value
    int result = lib.gp_widget_set_value(widget, valueptr.getPointer());
```

To my surprise, nothing crashes. To my dismay, the function doesn't seem to get the data at all. Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

The function gp_widget_set_value was generated by JNAerator based on libgphoto2. The generated function header including generated comment looks like this:

```
/**
 * Original signature : <code>int gp_widget_set_value(CameraWidget*, const void*)</code><br>
 * <i>native declaration : /usr/include/gphoto2/gphoto2-widget.h:840</i>
 */
int gp_widget_set_value(Gphoto2Library.CameraWidget widget, Pointer value);
```

The documentation of the actual C function from the Gphoto API docs:

> int gp_widget_set_value   (   CameraWidget *      widget,         const void * 
>     value   )
>
> Sets the value of the widget.
>
> Parameters
>       widget    a CameraWidget
>       value
>
> Returns
>       a gphoto2 error code.
>
> Please pass (char*) for GP_WIDGET_MENU, GP_WIDGET_TEXT,
>   GP_WIDGET_RADIO, (float) for GP_WIDGET_RANGE, (int) for
>   GP_WIDGET_DATE, GP_WIDGET_TOGGLE, and (CameraWidgetCallback) for
>   GP_WIDGET_BUTTON.

In case you are wondering, the last line refers to the widget type, and yes, I'm making very sure that that is correct.

Comment: What's your default encoding? Try to print the content of `byte_value` on the Java side using `Arrays.toString(...)`. It may have a zero byte right at the beginning.

Comment: I'm defining it myself, so there's not much chance of it being corrupted before being sent. I did check in the debugger just to make sure, and everything looks fine (the string I'm trying to pass is "Off", so it's pretty simple really).

Comment: Please show us the prototype of `gp_widget_set_value()`.  It is relevant, you know.

Comment: Did you check the string or the byte array? It's really not about the string you are trying to send but about the encoding it uses for `getBytes`. If it's using UTF-16, for example, then the first byte will definitely be 0 for "Off".

Comment: also, please show us all the documentation you have for `gp_widget_set_value()`.  Paste the documentation in the question.

Comment: The operating system and CPU architecture you are using are relevant, too.

Comment: @RealSceptic: The contents of byte_value are 79, 102, 102, so whatever it is, it's ASCII-conform.

Comment: @Mike Nakis: I've updated the post. The binding was created by JNAerator, which seems to have done a good job so far, so I didn't bother with it too much yet.

Comment: OS is Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, the CPU is an I7

Comment: Just note that you are not actually passing it a pointer to the beginning of the array. `byte_value[0]` evaluates to 79 on the Java side and that's passed by value to `ByteByReference` which stores it in a newly allocated space.

Comment: >>  and that's passed by value to ByteByReference which stores it in a newly allocated space.        --Oh Joy! thanks, that's some very relevant info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need anything complicated.  JNA takes care of most common C idioms.  JNAerator is giving you literally what's in the function declarations; it can't figure out the semantic difference between a C string, a char buffer, an array of char, or a pointer to a single char.

```
int gp_widget_set_value(Gphoto2Library.CameraWidget widget, String value);
```

Note that the memory passed to the native function in this case is temporary and will be disposed of when the function returns.  If you need the memory to stick around (not a good idea), you'd need to use `Memory` and maintain a reference to it.

Comment: You _might_ be able to get JNAerator to use `String` if your declaration uses `const char*`.

Comment: Thanks. I accepted this answer because it leads to the most readable result.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following to get the bytes in the proper encoding:

```
byte[] bytes = new_value.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ); //or .US_ASCII
```

But what you most probably need to do is to use [JNA's byte[] Native.toByteArray(String s)](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html#toByteArray%28java.lang.String%29)

If for some reason that does not work, then this should do it:

```
Pointer m = new Memory( new_value.length() + 1 ); //assumes ASCII
m.setString( 0, new_value );
int result = lib.gp_widget_set_value( widget, m );
```

Comment: Thanks. Both of those suggestions worked eventually... It turns out I had another problem preventing the value from being applied. But my initial attempt would still not have worked.

Comment: Gosh, Uncle Bob, I was sure you had tried that and it did not work, so I was wild goose chasing!

Comment: Sorry about that. First time working with JNA, still looking for the ins and outs...